# Alert Box "not showing" in Chrome - Off Screen?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm not quite sure what's going on here. I'm using the latest Google Chrome, and recently any Alert Box popups don't show up. They're THERE, because I have to hit enter/esc to be able to use my browser again.  This is for all alert boxes in the browser. I tried plugging an HDMI cable to see if it was really off screen and maybe I could see it if I extended my monitor, but to no avail.

I saw that there was a bug in 2012 that was similar to this, but that's obviously been fixed and shouldn't be relevant here.

EDIT: Version 39.0.2171.95

Comment: Please share the exact version number of your Chrome. "The latest version" is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry, added. (39.0.2171.95)

Comment: Looks like I've the same version, and I can't reproduce your issue. Can you provide a reproduceable example?

Comment: Same version, same issue.

Comment: I am still having this problem on Win 10  with Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing your dialog is indeed off screen, press [alt][space][m].
Then swing around with your mouse or press your arrow keys like hell and your dialog will eventually come in scope.
See also http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/42206189

Comment: Very odd... this isn't working for me. I can see the movement cursor appear over the address bar, and I can move it with my mouse or arrow keys on my display, but nothing comes up. The alert box WORKS because if I type something in and hit enter I get the result on my webpage. This is only occurring on one computer of mime, and I don't have anything crazy installed that may cause this.

Comment: This doesn't help anymore (well in 2017), because in Alert window doesn't have "window" menu, so unlike normal windows it can't be moved by hand...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. After much testing I was able to correct this by the following means

1. Settings> Show advanced settings
2. Scroll to bottom
3. Remove the checkmark from "use hardware acceleration when available"